# Replacing the activity indicator in the accessory view of a table cell with disclosure indicator

Tags: iphone

In one of my application i have a tableViewControlles with disclosure indicators in the accessory view. When user taps on a cell an activity indicator  is made the accessory view of tapped cell and another viewController is pushed in. When i go back to the tableView i want to show the disclosure indicator instead of the activity indicator ...How can i do this...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Either right before you push the new controller, or right as your popping out to the table view...reset the activity indicator. However I don't see the need for this unless you are downloading a file when you select a row and it takes some time to process before it loads the new controller. If this is the case, whenever you know the download is finished (either a notification..or whatever) just reset the disclosure indicator of the cell there.

Comment: thanks jesse.. inbetween the view transitions i am calling webservices to update the values in the pushed viewcontroller..